# Error when create composite index in PostgreSQL using liquibase change log

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

While trying to generate database using liquibase changelog in Postgres, I am getting following error:

> forIndexName is not allowed on postgresql

Following is my change log which is generating same error:

```
<changeSet author="chintan.patel" id="CP0001">
        <createIndex indexName="PK_USER" tableName="USER" unique="true">
            <column name="FIRSTNAME"/>
            <column name="MIDDLENAME"/>
            <column name="LASTNAME"/>
        </createIndex>
        <addPrimaryKey columnNames="FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME, LASTNAME" constraintName="PK_USER" forIndexName="PK_USER" tableName="USER"/>
    </changeSet>
```

This same change set works fine in Oracle.
Please suggest me, whats wrong here.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: remove the `forIndexName` attribute

Comment: Thanks for pointing it. I just skipped that attribute. Removing it worked for me. Thanks again.

Comment: With just removing `forIndexName` you *may* end up with 2 indexes, as *PostgreSQL automatically creates an index for each unique constraint and primary key constraint to enforce uniqueness. Thus, it is not necessary to create an index explicitly for primary key columns.* (I wrote *may* because the name you have given to the index is what PostgreSQL will give by default, but the docs doesn't mention that an existing index with the right name & definition is going to be re-used, or just the generated index will have another name).

Comment: Anyway, pretty sure that all RDBMS behave somewhat similar, I don't think you have to create both an index & a primary key for your tables. A primary key should be enough in any of them.